# Is it possible to vectorize this for-loop?

Tags: matlab, optimization

So, I am trying to optimize this code on Matlab, the only thing that I can do (I think) is to vectorize it. The problem is that all the guides that I found on vectorizing code were for very simple problems, so I don't know if it's even possible to vectorize this one.

```
h = zeros(1,length(t));
n = zeros(1,length(t));
b = zeros(1,length(t));
z = zeros(1,length(t));
V = zeros(1,length(t));
I = zeros(1,length(t));
delta_t = t(2) - t(1);
% Initial conditions
h(1) = 0.978936;
n(1) = 0.0244296;
b(1) = 0.205115;
z(1) = 0.00139361;
V(1) = -71.8723;

for i=1:(length(t)-1)
    h(i+1) = h(i) + delta_t*feval(@h_prime,V(i),h(i));
    n(i+1) = n(i) + delta_t*feval(@n_prime,V(i),n(i));
    b(i+1) = b(i) + delta_t*feval(@b_prime,V(i),b(i));
    z(i+1) = z(i) + delta_t*feval(@z_prime,V(i),z(i));
    minf = m_inf(V(i));
    pinf = p_inf(V(i));
    ainf = a_inf(V(i));
    if (t(i) >= t_app(1) && t(i) <= t_app(2))
        I(i) = Iapp;
    else I(i) = 0;
    end;
    V(i+1) = V(i) + delta_t*feval(@V_prime,V(i),h(i),n(i),b(i),z(i),minf,pinf,ainf,I(i));
end;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: all the fevals are functions, the most complex one is V_prime:

```
function dV = V_prime(V, h, n, b, z, minf, pinf, ainf, Iapp)  

% membrane potential (µF/cm^2)
Cm = 1;

% reverse potentials (mV)
EL  = -70;
ENa = 55;
EK  = -90;

% maximum conductances (mS/cm^2)
gL   = 0.05;
gNa  = 35;
gNaP = 0.20;        % varies between 0-0.41
gKdr = 6;
gA   = 1.4;
gM   = 1;

% ionic currents
INa  = gNa*(minf^3)*h*(V-ENa);
INaP = gNaP*pinf*(V-ENa);
IKdr = gKdr*(n^4)*(V-EK);
IA   = gA*(ainf^3)*b*(V-EK);
IM   = gM*z*(V-EK);
IL   = gL*(V-EL);

dV = (-(INa + INaP + IKdr + IA + IM + IL) + Iapp)/Cm;
```

Here is h_prime

```
function dh = h_prime(V, h)

h_inf = 1/(1+exp((V+45)/7));
T_h   = 0.1+0.75*(1/(1+exp((V+40.5)/6)));

dh = (h_inf - h)/T_h;
```

Comment: What is `h_prime` and other `prime`'s?

Comment: they are simply mathematic functions, I give the arguments and they return a value. I did that on other functions so my main code would look better

Comment: I don't think it is needed to post the functions too, since they only return float values.  Let me know if I am wrong

Comment: I think the first requirement to vectorization is to get rid of those fevals. So, those fevals are needed in the question. Still there is dependency, so removing fevals don't guarantee that vectorization is possible here. If those fevals are similar, maybe you can post one of them *if you can*.

Comment: if necessary, I can drag all those functions inside the main function, there is no problem at all

Comment: Ok, how about `h_prime`, `n_prime`, `b_prime` and `z_prime`. Are they similar? If so, can you post one of them too?

Comment: yes, they are very similar, I will post one of them, the others are the same, just the parameters change a bit.

Comment: Before you decide that vectorization is your solution you really need to profile the code to understand where time is spent. For a few years now Matlab uses a JIT compiler that makes most attempts to vectorize unproductive. There may be other ways...

Comment: hmm, I didn't know that, the thing is that the same code in C++ (using  10000000 points) is 39x approx. faster. I am about to get to the conclusion that there is not much hope for the matlab code

Comment: no, minf is simply, minf = 1/(1+exp(-(V+30)/9.5)); I just used a separate .m file for that

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but this is a separate file, V(1) is an argument. 
function f = m_inf(V)

f = 1/(1+exp(-(V+30)/9.5));

The code is working properly

Comment: Hmm, so because of the data dependency, to get complete vectorization (no loops at all) you need to create a single function, `f1` such that V(i+1) = f1(V(i). To do that, you need to convert everything else in terms of V(i), which just looks .. too big a task.  This doesn't guarantee vectorization, as next you need to map it somehow to all elements taking care of the dependency. Good luck anyway.

Comment: for vectorizing, your variables on a certain iteration must not depend on the previous one (or at least you must be able to convert them into that). Your case is the complete opposite of that. Biological potentials are intrinsically recursive, they depend on the past situation. Instead of trying to vectorizing (which I do not think you can) write the function in mex (C code, which does not seem too complicated based on the code you presented) and you then can use that with other code in MATLAB.

Comment: Agree with ASantosRibeiro, the loop you have got there is a *simulation* and you cannot vectorize a simulation how would you do that? This code seems to have been written with performance in mind you probably cannot do much more. The simulation is always going to take a lot of time. If you want it faster then probably writing a mex function is all you can do.

Comment: Btw. is any of the `_prime` variables stochastic (`z_prime` perhaps)? If you are drawing random numbers during the simulation this is where you can speed up by drawing all of them before hand.

Comment: no the variables are not random, I managed to speed the function taking off the function. Because when I profiled the code, the function times were taking a lot of time. Now the code is a lot faster, still slower than C++ though. I will follow ASantos advice and try to learn about mex. Thanks for the help